# C - scanf to pull a number in quotes only after a specific sequence of characters

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

Say I have a string like this:

```
Hello World - this is a line of textCOLOR="4"
```

and this string is stored in `buf[1000]`

As you can see this string has a color tag in the format of `COLOR="n"`. The number is what needs to be pulled (it can be between 1 and 56) and assigned to an `int` variable. I'd like for this tag to be able to be anywhere in the string.

I can run the following code to extract the color value:

```
int colorNumber = 1; //default value
if (scanf(buf, "%*[^\"]\"%2d[^\"]\"", &colorNumber)) {
    // work with number
}
```

and that works fine, but if the string were to contain a number or quote in it then the scanf would fail to produce the number.

I've tried a few variations of my second scanf argument, but those didn't work. I tried `"%*[^\"]COLOR=\"%2d[^\"]\""` but that doesn't seem to work at all.

I've looked through the man pages for scanf, but I couldn't find what I was looking for in there either.

Perhaps scanf is not the right tool for this? I'm willing to try other libraries/functions if necessary.

Comment: You should consider using `strstr` to look for the "COLOR" keyword; you can then process from that if it is found.

Comment: Scanf is not regex. Can't you just `atoi(strstr(buf, "COLOR=\"") + 7)`  or similar?

Comment: @Kamil  I think you're missing a `"`

Comment: @KamilCuk That actually works really well, thank you! I noticed that it works with 2 digits as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if (sscanf(buf, "%*[^C]COLOR=\"%d", &colorNUM) == 1)
```

The reason your attempted `"%*[^\"]COLOR"`... format didn't work is that the `%*[\"]` matches everything up to the `"`, skipping past the COLOR, so will then fail to match COLOR.  The above will fail if there's another `C` somwhere else in the string before `COLOR`, however.  To avoid that you're probably better off using `strstr`, possibly in a loop if `COLOR` might appear multiple places.

```
for (const char *p = buf; p = strstr(p, "COLOR"); ++p) {
    if (sscanf(p, "COLOR=\"%d", &colorNum) == 1) {
        // found a color number
```

Note also, trying to match characters after the `%d` is pointless as regardelss of whether they match or not, the returned values will be the same, so there's no way to tell.  If you want to ensure there's a `"` after the number, you need something like

```
int end = 0;
if (sscanf(p, "COLOR=\"%d\"%n", &colorNum, &end), end > 0)
```

by checking that `%n` wrote something to `end`, you're also checking that everything before the `%n` matched correctly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question Chris. Your solution makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. I think I may have been making it harder than it should have been.